# Is it okay to use chdir() in a shutdown function?

Tags: php, shutdown, chdir

I noticed my Autoloader was not working properly on destructors (after `die;`), because PHP changes the current directory on shutting down.

was:

```
D:\www\arsenal
```

got changed to:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21
```

I don't even know why it does that. I solved the Autoloader problem using `realpath` but was wondering what kind of other problems it may cause.

So, is it safe to use `chdir` to change it back in a function registered with `register_shutdown_function`? I tested it and totally solved the Autoloader problem, as well as `realpath` did (the shutdown function gets called before the destructors, don't know why either).

The catch is that i'm afraid of the consequences. I don't even know if PHP behaves this way in other platforms. I would really like to have more information on the subject.

I'm on Windows 7, using WAMP 2.2 (PHP 5.3.8, Apache 2.2.21).

Comment: Instead of going that route why don't you simply base your paths in the current dir the file is in `__DIR__`?

Comment: The `Autoloader`, for instance, has to require files that are not in the library folder itself. So there's no way to use it's location as reference without crippling portability.

Comment: With about injecting the path into the autoloader at construction phase?

Comment: I'm not looking for workarounds for the issues (I already solved it without `chdir` as I mentioned). I just wanted to know if it's safe to "normalize" things with `chdir` and more information about this behavior on other platforms.